# Custom google map on contact page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

I need to put a styled map on a contact page in WP.
I'd rather not use a plugin as it would be overkill, embedding on the other way won't allow me to customize layers, use placeholders, etc

I coded an example map on a static html page. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13823768/map/test.html

How do I get from here to wordpress?

**EDIT:** I'm working with a child theme so I put this in functions.php (in my child-theme dir)

```
function enqueue_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('google-map-api','https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&amp;language=it');
    wp_enqueue_script('google-map-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/map.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts');
?>
```

Looks ok so far but it needs `<body onload="initialize()">` too.
Do you know how I can add the onload to the body tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by creating a custom theme page template: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates or simply add the #map_canvas element in the "text" view of the WSYWYG content area of the page editor.

The next step is to add all of your map scripts, I would do this by enqueuing the scripts in your theme's functions.php by creating a callback function that is called on the wp_enqueue_scripts action: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script.
the function you will add to functions.php would look something like this(replacing the filepaths with your scripts):

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

I know you mentioned not wanting a plugin for overkill, but a plugin would allow portability of your code and would allow you to switch themes without losing your map code.  Adding a plugin and shortcode to render the #map_canvas element would not be much more time than adding the code to functions.php.  If your interested in writing a custom plugin, http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: Thank you! Almost there. I edited my post to add my code and hopefully find a solution for the <body onload="initialize()"> bit.

Comment: you could add $(document).on('load', function(){ initialize(); }); to your script file.